# tfs build is getting failed when releasebuild is true

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, release-management, ms-release-management

I am working on triggering release from TFS build and I have configured MS Release Management environment for the same.

TFS build is not successful when I make "ReleaseBuild=true". Error count is zero even though the build is getting failed. From some of the articles, I came to know that build agent account should be created as "Release Manager" in RM client. Now Build Agent is running under NETWORK SERVICES account.

I have few doubts:

1. Do I need to change Build Agent identity to windows identity and create that user as release manager in RM client?
2. If yes, what are the necessary permissions to be given for that account in both windows and in RM.
3. If No, how I could create NETWORK SERVICES as “release manager” in RM

Please help me to resolve this road blocking issue.

Comment: is the release actually getting triggered? do you have the link set up between a build and a release Template?

Comment: release is not getting triggered. Yes, i have selected the build definition in the release template.

Comment: Click 'View Log', and look for that step 'Run the Release Management Build process for the Current Configuration'. You should get information about the Release process.

Comment: Also: do you have a RM client installed on the Build Agent box?

Comment: Yes, RM client & RM server are installed in the Build Agent box only.

Comment: @joerage from the 'View Log', i have identified the same issue mentioned in the question. I have created NETWORK SERVICES as “release manager” in RM. Now getting another error related to tfs url, working on that now. Thank you for the comment.